# hook_form_FORM_ID_alter in theme file to toggle field visibility

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I have a boolean check box that I want to control the visibility of an entity-reference field below it.  By default, this check box is unchecked, which means the entity-reference field should not be shown.

I've tried a handful of things in my .theme file, but I can't seem to solve the problem.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function mytheme_form_node_news_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface 
  &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['field_news_top_story_image']['#states'] = [ 
    'visible' => [ 
        ':input[name="field_news_topstory"]' => ['checked' => TRUE] 
    ]
];
```

}

node_news_form (and eventually node_news_edit_form once I figure this out) appears to be the form I want to affect.  field_news_topstory is my checkbox and field_news_top_story_image is the entity-reference field I want to hide* until field_news_topstory is checked.  *I've set this field to disabled in Manage Form Display.

Am I close?  :)

EDIT: Had my code backwards, but still not working.

Comment: try with `$form['field_news_top_story_image']['#states'] = [
       'visible' => [
         ':input[name="field_news_topstory"]' => ['checked' => TRUE]
     ]
   ];`

Comment: @berramou - How does the initial state of field_news_top_story_image get set to hidden (or disabled)?  I was thinking I'd set it to disabled in Manage Form Display, but i'm not sure that's the right move.  Thanks!

Comment: field_news_top_story_image will be initially hidden because it has state and the rule in the state is to make it visible only if the field_news_topstory input checked, so it remain hidden until the checkbox input checked

Comment: @berramou   Thanks for clarifying.  I'm still not seeing what I need.  I've posted my updated code above.  Perhaps I have the wrong form id?  If I view the source of the two forms I'm trying to affect I see 

<input data-drupal-selector="edit-node-news-form" type="hidden" name="form_id" value="node_news_form" />

and 

<input data-drupal-selector="edit-node-news-edit-form" type="hidden" name="form_id" value="node_news_edit_form" />

Comment: I added a list field to my content type and changed ':input[name="field_news_topstory"]' => ['checked' => TRUE] to 'select[name="field_news_test_field"]' => ['value' => 'Yes']  and now my field_news_top_story_image visibility can be toggled.

Can I not use a boolean as shown in my original post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of banging on this, I found the right combo.  We don't have a custom admin theme, so I ended up moving this code in to a custom module.

The important part I was missing was **[value]** in ':input[name="field_news_topstory[value]"]' => ['checked' => TRUE]

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function mymodule_form_node_news_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['field_news_top_story_image']['#states'] = [
       'visible' => [
         ':input[name="field_news_topstory[value]"]' => ['checked' => TRUE]
       ]
   ];
}
```